# Loading html on a div without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I want to load an `iframe` using just javascript, so far I've been using this:

```
$(".punctis-social-box").html("<iframe></iframe>");
```

But since it is the only instruction I have that uses jQuery, I'll like not to depend any more on jQuery.

Comment: @Amadan I deleted my comment, I obviously misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not the best way to start:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("punctis-social-box");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "<iframe></iframe>";
}
```

Or using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".punctis-social-box");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "<iframe></iframe>";
}
```

In order to avoid all *bad practices*<sup>TM</sup> you may use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) instead of explicit change of inner HTML:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".punctis-social-box"),
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

while (element.firstChild) {                  // the fastest way
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);  // to clear the contents
}
element.appendChild(iframe);                  // adding new <iframe>
```

Comment: @PeeHaa How is this not the best way to start? His answer is completely valid.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is one of the worst things one can do, because it destroys all nodes in the element. Also writing HTML in JS is often not advised.

Comment: I have just one element called punctis-social-box, so the For cycle is still useful?

Comment: @PeeHaa I simply "*rephrase*" the OP's code. Of course you can use `appendChild` etc, but first you need to remove all content from the element. Why to overcomplicate?

Comment: @PeeHaa That's only if you overright innerHTML, can you not just append to it (ie. innerHTML += "value") ?

Comment: @DomingoSL class selector returns a set of elements in so called `NodeList` which may contain many elements. Of course you can always get only the first one with `elements[0]`.

Comment: @DomingoSL If you are sure you'll only have the 1 element with that class, you won't need to loop, just do elements[0].innerHTML instead

Comment: Because it is "the correct way ™". And considering the fact OP tries to move away from bad practices (jQuery) might as well show the correct way.

Comment: I saw i the other question that getElementsByClassName is from html5, so will this method be compatible with older browsers?

Comment: I checked an it dont, http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname At least not with IE 8 (which is the most used so far)

Comment: @DomingoSL You can see the compatibility table here: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/.

Comment: @PeeHaa OK. How about now? :)

Comment: Somewhat better. Although I'm not sure if OP really wants all children gone. But if OP wants the children gone deleting the children is [still preferred](http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild).

Comment: @DomingoSL: The funny thing is that the more advanced method (`.querySelector`/`.querySelectorAll`) is available in IE8 ;) http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score 4):

Method 1:

```
var social_boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('punctis-social-box');
social_boxes[0].innerHTML += '<iframe></iframe>'; // add to first element, loop thru "social_boxes" if you want to add iframe to all elements
```

Method 2 (better):

```
var social_boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('punctis-social-box');
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
social_boxes[0].appendChild(iframe); // add to first element, loop thru "social_boxes" if you want to add iframe to all elements
```

Comment: There is no `getByClassName` method in JavaScript.

Comment: @VisioN Yes, there is, but it is not standard until HTML5 (although FF has had it since v3), if you want compatibility you would have to use nastier methods.

Comment: I really need a cross browser more compatible solution, so I need the "nastier methods" :)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes