# Html loads after a second click

Tags: html, dojo

I have declared a div in abc.html as,

```
 <div id="ICD" dojoType="dijit/layout/ContentPane" closable="false"
                                style="background-color: #F4F4F4;font-size: 11px; overflow:overlay"
                                onDblClick="dbClickGraphical" align="center">
```

and i'm using href to load another HTML into this div

```
dijit.byId('ICD').set('href', "zzz.html");
```

But This,zzz.html loads after second click/time

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with the problem demonstrated? (often times you'll find the problem when trying to make one).

Comment: So basically you want page1.html to load in <div class="test"> </div> and then load page2.html to said <div>, but it is taking 2 click to load?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript) and see if you can change your code to something like that.

Comment: yes.. it s taking 2 click to load - skibbi_bizzle

Comment: well you have it set to (onDblClick="dbClickGraphical")

Comment: as commented by @skibbi_bizzle you need to use `onClick` if you want to fire on a single click instead of `onDblClick` which will fire on `double clicks`.