# How can I load a webpage into a <div> element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new to Javascript and I have a question about loading a webpage into a div element ('content-window') on my website. I want to open a webpage in that div, in this case http://www.fdsa.com?ID=1. I've to write the following line in order to select the div element.

```
var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
```

Can someone tell me how can I load a webpage into this side div? I've tried a lot (but I've failed of course). For example, the following line won't work:

```
sidediv.location.assign = "http://www.fdsa.com?ID=1";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: you could use an i frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use an `<iframe>` tag as follows:

```
<div>
  <iframe src="http://www.fdsa.com?ID=1">
</div>
```

or build it programatically:

`document.getElementById("content-window").innerHTML='<iframe src="http://www.fdsa.com?ID=1">'`

you could use more `<iframe>` information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

**HTMLCODE :**

```
  <body onload="loadHtml()">
    <div id="content-window"></div>
  </body>
```

**CSS CODE :**

```
#content-window {
    width: 100%;

}

#content-window object{
    width: 100%;

}
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
function loadHtml() {
    document.getElementById("content-window").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="http://www.fdsa.com?ID=1"></object>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is AJAX, if you don't want it `embeded` inside and rather actually `inline` as part of the document.

The easiest (and for the sake of convenience, I will post it here) method utilizes jQuery, it's so easy it's incredible, obviously there are other methods but I have to post this one (I use it everywhere):

Here is the function:

[`.load("http://url.com/")`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)