# How to load HTML page into DIV in JSP ( nothing loads )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Can anybody give me advice on how to make it work?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divpage"></div>
    <script>
      $("#divpage").load("http://localhost:3000/annotation/testuser/demo.html");
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

The browser has to load the full DOM, before you can manipulate it with javascript, 
In Jquery use `.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#divpage").load("http://localhost:3000/annotation/testuser/demo.html");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your script block out of the body and up in the head section.  Then, wrap your JQuery like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#divpage").load("http://localhost:3000/annotation/testuser/demo.html");
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
</script>
```