# How do I make a post and return the contents into <div> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, http-post

I came across the question : [How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

I want to basically do the same thing with POST data but I'm not sure where to start.

The existing script works with get requests only?

```
<script>
      function load_home(){
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="home.html" ></object>'; 
  }
</script>
```

I would like to avoid using jQuery if I can avoid it.

Comment: same link also has an answer where an ajax call (pure js) is made to fetch the html. Did you tried that code with `post` request?

Comment: I did not, and I'm not sure how the syntax would look.    This is the function that gets a request.                                                                              function load_home (e) {
   (e || window.event).preventDefault();
   var con = document.getElementById('content')
   ,   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
     con.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
   }
 xhr.open("GET", "http://www.yoursite.com/home.html", true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
 xhr.send();
}

Comment: check the docs http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same ajax example you had posted in your comment, by changing the `http://www.yoursite.com/home.html` to `home.html`

Similar to below

In Javascript,

```
<script>
function load_home(e, getwhat){ // <--- send which html file to get and display the content in argument 'getwhat'
    e.preventDefault();
    var con = document.getElementById('content');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", getwhat, true); // <-- this is post request
    //xhr.open("GET", getwhat, true); // <-- this is get request
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            con.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

In HTML,

```
<a href="#" onclick="load_home(event, 'home.html')"> HOME </a>
<a href="#" onclick="load_home(event, 'aboutus.html')"> ABOUT US </a>
<a href="#" onclick="load_home(event, 'service.html')"> SERVICE </a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a POST example

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `POST`

Answer (score 0):

The best aproach is to use  jquery like this working demo

**html**

```
 <nav id="menu" class="menu-side">
    <a href="../pages/theAboutPage.html" id="about">About</a>
    <a href="../pages/theHelpPage.html" id="help">Help</a>
    <a href="../pages/theContactPage.html" id="contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
<div id="target">
    <!-- content is being loaded here from other .html files -->
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
    $(function() {
    var $menu = $('#menu'), 
        $target = $('#target');

    $menu.on('click', '> a', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        event.preventDefault();
        $target.load($this.attr('href'));
    });
})
```

Comment: this example does not have a POST example, and uses jQuery which I would prefer to avoid.