# Opening latest file from html

Tags: html

I have a list of `html` files in a folder with naming convention `file-name + time-stamp` (for example `report122345`). Here `122345` is file creation hour minutes second. I want to select the latest file and open it by another html code.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you cannot do in pure HTML. You’ll need to add some Javascript.
 (Look at [How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript) )

Basically you need 1 or  2 web services :

1. Returns all filenames, so you javascript can chose the one to load
2. Load the demanded file

If conditions are not dependents on client entry, you can combine both of them.