# Open links in a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a menu in a DIV (wrapper). Now i would like to open the links from the menu in another DIV (TEST). Until now i found only this method (not nice) with an iframe. Is there another solution - perhaps with javascript (but without ajax or php)?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards, Ronny

```css
body { margin:0; background-color: #333333;}
    
    .wrapper{
     width: 960px; 
     margin: 0 auto; 
     position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        /* background: url("ronny_logo.jpg"); */
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 10;
     margin-top: 120px;
    }
    
    
    /* MENU */
    #main_menu{
        margin:0px;
     padding:0;
        height: 150px;
     /* width: 100%;      /* Breite vom Hauptmenü Container */
        padding: 0px 0;
        /*overflow: hidden; Remove this*/
     position: fixed;
     background-color: black;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    #main_menu li{
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 130px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 120px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #main_menu li a, #footer_menu li a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    #main_menu .logo{
        background: none;
        width: 445px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #main_menu li a:hover, #footer_menu li a:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #main_menu li .submenu{
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top:100%;
    }
    #main_menu li .submenu:hover{
        display: block;
    }
    #main_menu li a:hover + .submenu{
        display: block;
    }
    #main_menu li .submenu li{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #main_menu li .submenu li a{
        font-size: 9pt;
    }
    /* COLORS */
    .red, .red .submenu{ background-color: #ed3327; }
    .blue, .blue .submenu{ background-color: #9dbdd5; }
    .green, .green .submenu{ background-color: #6fb145; }
    .orange, .orange .submenu{ background-color: #f5832e; }
    .yellow, .yellow .submenu{ background-color: #f6ec35; }
    

    
    .TEST{
     width: 960px; 
     margin: 0 auto; 
        font-size: 19pt;
     color: #FF0000;
        z-index: 10;
     margin-top: 120px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>R.O.N.N.Y | Containertest</title>
    <META NAME="author" CONTENT="R.O.N.N.Y">
    <META NAME="publisher" CONTENT="R.O.N.N.Y">
    <META NAME="description" CONTENT="Ulla Neugebauer, Das Presshaus, Neugeboren in Hebammenhand, Ladendorf, Hebamme">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="reply to" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="language" CONTENT="de">
    <META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="Neugebauer, Ulla, Hebamme, Geburt, Ladendorf, Presshaus, Neugeboren, Hebammenhand, dasPresshaus">
    <META NAME="robots" CONTENT="index">
    <META NAME="page-topic" CONTENT="Geburt, Hebamme, Gesundheit, sonstiges">
    <META NAME="audience" CONTENT="alle, anfänger, azubis, erwachsene, experten, fans, fortgeschrittene, frauen, jugendliche, kinder, profis, schüler, studenten">
    <META NAME="revisit-after" CONTENT="01 month">
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico" />
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        
            
                <ul id="main_menu">
                    <li class="logo">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="ronny_logo.jpg" alt="Logo"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="red">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="green">
                        <a href="#">Evenementen</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="http://www.a1.net" target="irgendwas">Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="blue">
                        <a href="#">Bus</a>
    
                    </li>
                    <li class="orange">
                         <a href="contact.html" target="irgendwas">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
      </div>      
        
        <div class="TEST">
             
        <iframe src="home.html" style="width:300px; height:600px;" frameborder="0" name="irgendwas"></iframe>
        
        
         <p>fadsfdsfdas</p>
       <p>dfsadfaf</p>
       <p>d</p>
       <p>d</p>
       <p>d</p>
       <p>d</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>gg</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>h</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>g</p>
       <p>g</p>
            
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: lookout]

Comment: Read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first

Comment: You can't do this. To retrieve data from the server (the other pages) you have to send a request to it (using full request like `iframe` or "partial" request using `ajax`). You can insert the other pages content into your homepage and hide it, and show the selected content when user click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not solve your problem, but you can use jquery to load an external html file (or parts thereof) into a div. This is discussed in the following link and answered by @Giliweed

[How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

```
function load_home(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html" ></object>';
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you Aaron,
but i'm doing something wrong. the other HTML-page opens but the content is displayed in a box (like in an iframe). But in my code there's only this one:


    <div id="container">
    <section id="content">

and I'm calling the id "content" from the function.



please take a look at the screenshot:
http://i67.tinypic.com/30axok1.jpg


if I'm trying to call the id "container" nothing is displayed :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not certain what you're wanting to make it look like... are you trying to run both container and content in the grey box at the same time? Or are you wanting each to fill the whole area and change over on different pages? It might be a simple syntax issue.
Would it be possible to see a snippet of your markup on jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: Hi - I have uploaded the hole page zipped @ http://workupload.com/file/dkcYLiMW
Please download the ZIP and take a look at the sourcecode. If you click the "KONTAKT" button, you can see my problem....
The content of the KONTAKT should look like the 1st site (Start) with the slideshow. It should have the same width.....so the text sould fill out the complete lightgrey box.

Thank's a lot for your help and patience!!!!