# How to merge several html files into one page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a (lot) too large html file with more than 1500 lines. I'd like to split it into serveral file and merge them. It would be more maintainable et readable.

For example.

Page1:

```
<h1> Title 1 <h2>
<div> my div </div>
```

Page2:

```
<h1> Title 2 <h2>
<div> my div </div>
```

Then merge and display:

Page.html

```
<h1> Title 1 <h2>
<div> my div </div>
<h1> Title 2 <h2>
<div> my div </div>
```

That way, I can change one module and find it easily.

Is there a pure html or JS library?
In .Net, it would be partial view. I am working with Bootstrap, tabs and modal. So Iframe is not the solution.
Thanks,

Stéphane.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Yep, you are right. That's it. I didn't know how to phrase my question. Thanks.

Comment: are you able to use php?  than you can include this files

Comment: I didn't want to use server side solution because it is just for templating. But if it is an easy solution to implement why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only concern is concating the files and you are using a UNIX based system (Linux, iOS), you can just type the command `cat * > output.html` into the shell and get all your files in one output.html.

If you are planning to create a website, where not only concat HTML files, but also various of other steps (minifying, CSS prefixing, SASS->CSS conversion etc.), you could use a Grunt or Gulp build process. There's e.g. a grunt-contrib-concat plugin which can be used for your exact use case.

Comment: This would result in an invalid html out file with one file appearing after the other, any browser would reject it.

Comment: Hi, my aim is not production, but for templating. After the website will be dynamic and made with MVC .Net. For example tables will be generated serverside. But for now I having these 50 rows tables that takes hips of lines. 
So yes, what I want is to organise my code not my rendering.