# Embed snippet of HTML in HTML document with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am creating an HTML document and I want to embed an HTML snippet from a separate file (not a full HTML document) into it.

Suppose the document I want to embed into is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
(stuff)
<placeholder />
</body>
</html>
```

and the code to embed is this:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel lucilius consequat adolescens ut, ex 
atomorum forensibus efficiendi mei. Eam adhuc regione eu, mei ex alia 
posidonium. Duis dicam postea mel id. Munere dolore ut eam, eam diam 
causae docendi id. At persius dolores eam, ea sea omnesque democritum, 
erroribus dissentiunt pro ut.</p>
```

Notice that the code I want to embed is **not** a complete HTML document; just a snippet. How would I embed that where the placeholder is in the main file using JavaScript?

Comment: Where do you get the snippet from?

Comment: Is the snippet already in a variable?

Comment: jQuery allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @Adjit, this is not a duplicate. I am not loading a page; only a snippet, and I have no interest in loading it in a <div>.

Comment: @SYZYGY-DEV333 Not the same question per se, but the same methods are applied. You don't need to load it into a `<div>` that is personal preference. Regardless, if you read all of the answers in that question you will find the same answer that was posted and marked correct here. You clearly have no interest in reading either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are accepting a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) solution, this task becomes trivial:

```
$('placeholder').load('path/to/file.html');
```

Using [`jQuery#load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get a local file (`path/to/file.html`) and put its contents into the `placeholder` element.

Read more about [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) selectors [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), but know that jQuery will generally accept all CSS selectors with some modifications.

---

If jQuery is not an option, then there is still a fairly succinct way to accomplish this in "vanilla" javascript using [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

```
function loadFileIntoElement(filePath, elementSelector) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var fileContents = this.responseText;
    document.querySelector(elementSelector).innerHTML = fileContents;
  });
  request.open("GET", filePath);
  request.send();
}

loadFileIntoElement('path/to/file.html', 'placeholder');
```

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) should also accept all valid CSS selectors.