# Best approach to replace iframes

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, design-patterns, responsive-design

Have an open ended question. 
I have a html form which contains multiple iframes with various urls as their sources (src attribute). 
My question is - 
1. are there any risks in general to have iframes in a web page? Like I heard that MS edge doesn't support iframes as such - is that true? 
2. What's the best approach( and why?) to replace these iframes considering the urls used as sources are not having their own API to be used?

P.S:- all the urls return html streams which are rendered within these iframes.

Looking for some directions here as I am pretty lost in here.  Thanks in advance!

Arka

Comment: why do you have to rewrite it?

Comment: Not exactly I want,  but what if I have to? Also,  is there a risk in using iframes? Do each and every browser completely support iframes?

Comment: if you want to see if you can use iframes look at this page: http://caniuse.com/#search=iframe

Comment: Thanks..will check on that! Any suggestions on how to replace the iframes?

Answer (score 2):

Re: replacing the iframes, you could possibly load the urls via AJAX or script tags or whatever you want and then bind them to divs. That's heavily dependent on what your frames are doing...

**Edit:** pasted from my comment below, for example, if you wanted to do this with jQuery, just put this script in your page someplace that makes sense:

```
$.ajax(url).done(function(data) {
    $("#divId").html(data);
});
```

Comment: These iframes are used only to load html data from other sources.

Comment: Great, then just do something like (jQuery):

    $.ajax(url).done(function(data) {
        $("#divId").html(data);
    });

Comment: Thanks for the response.. One question,  will this work if 'data' itself contains a whole html document starting with <html>tags? Just being curious.. Will check myself in sometime though

Comment: In that case you probably need to adapt something similar to what's being suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32671301/1440122