# how do you link/target files in a flexbox page to be viewed in 3 different div containers on the same flexbox page

Tags: javascript, html, flexbox

I saw this page [How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)
But I want to link to 3 different div containers from 3 menus that are in a separate div container.  (Im changing from frames to flexbox)
my set up has a master menu on the right side that links to three menu div.  (menu-A menu-B menu-C)  these send files to the corresponding div for display of the file.  (so div menu-A sends the file to div view-A; menu-B to view-B and same for menu-C)
This is an offline note taking "app" (pure html5 and css3 only) I wrote to help students be organized, get files from me/share files with others  and keep notes.  I choose html as it runs in all OS and can support the many languages my students use (I teach overseas)

Is this possible with flexbox?  - I set up a flexbox master file that looks like my frames set up, but cant figure out how to send files from the master menu to the 3 menu divs and then to the 3 viewer div.  Easy in frames, but how to in flexbox?  All answers I find are to send to one div on the same page.  My master-menu has about 80 links each going to either menu-A, Menu-B or menu-C.
I just began to learn javascript so I know I have much to learn!