# Trying to make it change page in a div when I swipe the finger

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

Trying to change page in a div when I swipe a finger left or right. Not up and down because one of the site I have to scroll down.

With this code I found here 
http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/
I can easy change the background color by swipe left or right. But I want to load a external page in a div instead.

I have try with jquery
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

And also basic javascript that I found here
[How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

I have try with both use same div that the swipe code have (swipebox) but also create a new div (page) to see if it help but no luck with that.

To make sure it does happen something I did make the code to change the color of the div and it does that why I still have the background color change to see if the javascript works and it does.

````
            function processingRoutine() {
                var swipedElement = document.getElementById(triggerElementID);
                if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
                         document.getElementById("swipeBox").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="http://www.yahoo.com" ></object>';
                         swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
                } else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
                         $('#page').load("http://www.google.se");
                         swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                }
            }


```HTML
<body>
        <div id="swipeBox" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'swipeBox');"  ontouchend="touchEnd(event);" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" ontouchcancel="touchCancel(event);" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div id="page" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
</body>

That I trying to do is when I swipe finger to the left it open a page in fullscreen in the div and when I swipe my finger to the right it open another page
````

Comment: Are you trying to swap the elements only, or just redirect the whole new page by swiping the screen?

Comment: Just swap the element, if I redirect the page to a new page I can't go back.