# How to call an Angular component on click event [Angular]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm not an expert in Angular. I followed some answers from internet also. Specially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript). I've a button from where I want to call a user defined method `onPress`.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="dls-menu-item" style="float: right;">
    <button (click)="onPress()"></button>
</div>

<div id="comp-render">
        <-----Here i want that component to be rendered
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class AnalyticsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}


    onPress() {
        console.log("clicked");
        document.querySelector('#comp-render').innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="mycomp.html" ></object>';
    }
}
```

Where **mycomp.html** is:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>This is a custom component.</p>
<button>Click</button>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do it.

Comment: You want to when you click onPress you display your mycom.html?

Comment: @devpato. Yes Sir exactly. Actually right now mycomp.html may look stupid but once i know how it is done, then i will extend its code further.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<div class="dls-menu-item" style="float: right;">
    <button (click)="onPress()"></button>
</div>

<div id="comp-render" *ngIf="display">
    <mycomp></mycomp>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts file**

```
 ...
 display = false;
 onPress() {
   this.display = true;
   /*if you want the component to show and hide on click pressed, use 
   use this line
   this.display = !this.display;*/
 }
```

**Working code:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d21pkn

Comment: alternatively you can also add new component as sub route using a combination of router and router-outlet then navigate to the route on button click