# ERROR TypeError: "jit_nodeValue_3(...).toggle is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I'm working on an Angular project. I wanted to add a month picker that would turn up on click of a text field at the nav bar. I'm using `primeng` components like `<p-calendar>` and `<p-overlay>`. Its a huge project in itself and I've to add `calendar` widget. So I'll show you my part of code only.

**navigation.component.html**

```
<div class="dls-menu-item" style="float: right; margin-right: 200px;">
    <input type="text" (click)="op.toggle($event)">
</div>

<p-overlayPanel #op>
  <div id="comp-render">
    <div class="all-container">
      <p>Time selection</p><br>
      <div>
        <p-calendar view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy"...></p-calendar>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

But the moment I click on the input field, I get this error:
[image]

My research on this error says that it is related to `MD Bootstrap`. But [this](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/angular/error-typeerror-jit_nodevalue_3-toggle-is-not-a-function-in-angular-6/) answer is not working for me. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795311/how-to-call-an-angular-component-on-click-event-angular/58795444#58795444) technique but it's not performing the way we want. And my findings says that `(click)="op.toggle($event)` is the root cause. Please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: toggle is jquery function right ?

Comment: @TonyNgo. Yes it is. It is also in typescript. The above is a template code directly from the `primeng` documentation. They've written it that way. Here is the link https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/overlaypanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reply can you try to create typings.d.ts and put this code here into it

```
interface JQuery<any> {
    tooltip(params: any): any;
}
```

Then in your tsconfig.json

```
"typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "src/typings.d.ts" // add here
        ],
```

Comment: Ok Sir. I'll create a fresh project and then try this solution.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you try to trigger the popover toggle from a non-prime element. It appears you need to add pInput to the input (or div and move the click handler) and then it will work.

```
<div class="dls-menu-item" style="float: right; margin-right: 200px;">
    <input type="text" (click)="op.toggle($event)" pInput><!--Add pInput-->
</div>

<p-overlayPanel #op>
  <div id="comp-render">
    <div class="all-container">
      <p>Time selection</p><br>
      <div>
        <p-calendar view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy"...></p-calendar>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

Comment: I fixed this issue long time ago. But I appreciate your efforts. I'll surely show this answer to my tech lead. Let's see what she has to say about this.

Comment: Worked for me in the same situation; this should be marked as the real answer (instead of the "typings" answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please check that ngx-menu is imported in your module in which you are using it. Basically if you are using multiple module and if you are not importing it in the module in which you are using ngx-menu then it will throw this error. So import ngx-menu in that specific module to solve this error. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered console error **jit_nodevalue_3(...) is not a function** while using Angular 7 and [Mat-Menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview).

The reason behind this error was the mat-menu element being declared with the same name as a click handler function I was using.

```
<mat-menu #onClickItem="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="onClickItem()">Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Renaming the click function solved the problem.

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="doSomething()">Item 1</button>
```

Hope this helps someone.