# In Django , how to display a html file within a webpage inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, django

Amateur here.I am working on a project.
I wanted to display the html file in the div.I came across this [How do I load an HTML page in a <div> using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)
. I have come across issue here.
In

```
function load_home()
         {
                document.getElementsByClassName("Analytic_area").innerHTML='<object type="html" data={% static 'app1\Venues_location.html' %}" ></object>;' 
         }
```

The problem is with

> data={% static 'app1\Venues_location.html' %}"

It asks me to put ';' where there is need and because of this, on runtime the path doesn't parse correctly.

[Here is Vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBeTx.png)

[Home is the button ,clicking on which a html will be displayed in the div below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKnJa.jpg)

Comment: Yeah that is wrong on multiple levels. Do you want to load the html dynamically with Ajax? or just include it in the page when the page renders?

Comment: @EneP Well Html is generated dynamically in my project.So i added a button which when clicked loads the webpage.So dynamically it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# views.py
def venues_location(request):
    return render(request, 'app1\Venues_location.html')
```

Then in your js:

```
function load_home(){

fetch('/venues_location') // or whatever url you assign to that view
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementsByClassName("Analytic_area").innerHTML=data);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add anything to urls.py? Only issue right now is getting the address right.

Comment: If am getting right , the function load home sending the  request  fetch the html I want inn the  div.This request goes to url.py in which i have added of the view, from there it goes to view.py where venues_location(request)  is accessed and returns the desired html file.
I am getting 404 even though the url is correct.

Comment: Try to use {% url '<url_name>' %} template tag then.

Comment: this worked in resolving the url but html file still isn't visible on the div.In Terminal window  code returned is  200.
I am really grateful to you for helping  me out , its annoying to keep taking your time.

Comment: Inspect the html source code and see if the code is actually there.

Comment: `  
async function load_home() {
             let url = "{% url 'venues_location' %}"

            Analytic_area.innerHTML = await (await fetch(url)).text();
          }    
`
and it was able to load the elements but couldn't display it, maybe because it contained many scripts.
but loading a simple html file was displayed successfully.