# Can I load an HTML file with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

Is it possible to link an html document on an innerHTML element rather than including the HTML in quotes?

```
headerTemplate.innerHTML = header.html
```

My reason for this is to separate the HTML from the javascript file and make it easier to edit the HTML in VS Code using code completion.

Comment: Why is it important that you use `innerHTML`? There are multiple ways to dynamically load markup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17636528/1264804

Comment: It does not, I want to have a separate file containing the HTML for the reason stated above.

Comment: That's exactly what those answers provide. Your problem isn't clear, and you didn't answer my first question.